# useRoute redirectedFrom is undefined when redirecting using navigateTo in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, nuxtjs3

I am using navigateTo to change pages like so:

```
navigateTo('/app/documents/all-documents')
```

After successfully getting to that page I am trying to implement a breadcrumb to go back to the previous route. However, useRoute's redirectedFrom is `undefined`

```
const route = useRoute()
console.log(route.redirectedFrom) //undefined
```

I don't know if my doing navigateTo correctly or if I misunderstood the use of `redirectedFrom`.

Nuxt3 Docs
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-route

Answer (score 0):

Try [useRouter()](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-router#based-on-history-api) instead, which includes the `back()` function

> `back()`: Go back in history if possible, same as `router.go(-1)`.

```js
const router = useRouter()

router.back()
```